# probability of the price having n positive consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas

This table is a pandas dataframe. Can someone help me out with writing function that show the probability of price up for 5 consecutive days in a row for the past 1000 days. So I will know the probability of price up for tomorrow if the past 4 days' price has been increasing.

Appreciate if any help.[image]

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd

binance=ccxt.binance()

def get_price(pair):

 df=binance.fetch_ohlcv(pair,timeframe="1d",limit=1000) #limit = 30 
 df = pd.DataFrame(df).rename(columns={0:"date",1:"open",2:"high",3:"low",4:"close",5:"volume"})
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='ms') + pd.Timedelta(hours=8) 
 df.set_index("date",inplace=True)
 return df    
df=get_price("BTC/USDT")

df["daily_return"]=df.close.pct_change()
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand? Have you attempted to write any code at all?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Random comment, I think based on context you're after [empirical probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_probability), in which case this is a simple one-liner using pandas [rolling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-rolling/). If this isn't the case, you probably need to explain what you mean by "probability" or explain in words what you're after.

```py
df["probability_5"] = (df["daily_return"] > 0).rolling(5).mean()
df[["daily_return", "probability_5"]].head(15)
```

Output:

```
                     daily_return  probability_5
date                                            
2017-08-17 08:00:00           NaN            NaN
2017-08-18 08:00:00     -0.041238            NaN
2017-08-19 08:00:00      0.007694            NaN
2017-08-20 08:00:00     -0.012969            NaN
2017-08-21 08:00:00     -0.017201            0.2
2017-08-22 08:00:00      0.005976            0.4
2017-08-23 08:00:00      0.018319            0.6
2017-08-24 08:00:00      0.049101            0.6
2017-08-25 08:00:00     -0.008186            0.6
2017-08-26 08:00:00      0.013260            0.8
2017-08-27 08:00:00     -0.006324            0.6
2017-08-28 08:00:00      0.017791            0.6
2017-08-29 08:00:00      0.045773            0.6
2017-08-30 08:00:00     -0.007050            0.6
2017-08-31 08:00:00      0.037266            0.6
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to kknow the  probability of price up for 5 consecutive days in a row for the past 1000 days. So I will know the probability of price up for tomorrow if the past 4 days' price has been increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to frame the question properly, I believe you are trying to calculate the relative frequency of n-consecutive postive or negative days of price series/array.

Some research:
https://medium.com/@mikeharrisny/probability-in-trading-and-finance-96344108e1d9

Please see my implementation bellow, using a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

random_prices = [100, 90, 95, 98, 99, 98, 97, 100, 99, 98]
df = pd.DataFrame(random_prices, columns=['price'])

def consecutive_days_proba(pandas_series, n, positive=True):
   # Transform to daily returns
   daily_return = pandas_series.pct_change()

   # Drop NA values, this makes the original series n-1
   daily_return.dropna(inplace=True)

   # Count the total number of days in the new series
   total_days = len(daily_return)

   if positive:
       # count the number of n consecutive days with positive returns
       consecutive_n =  ((daily_return > 0).rolling(n).sum() == n).sum()
   else:
       # count the number of n consecutive days with negative returns
       consecutive_n =  ((daily_return < 0).rolling(n).sum() == n).sum()

   return ((consecutive_n / total_days) * 100).round(2)

consecutive_days_proba(df['price'], n=3, positive=True)
```

So this returns 11.11% which is 1/9. Although the original series is a length of 10, I dont' think it makes sense to use the null days as part of the base.